# Подсветка синтаксиса в файлах другого расширения?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Я так понимаю что phpstorm подсвечивает синтаксис исходя из расширеня файлов. Но у меня хитрый проект, где php файл переименованы как asp. Как в таком случае включить подсветку и все фишки phpstorm? Спасибо.

Comment: В настройка IDE обычно бывает список расширений для конкретных видов файлов, стоит поискать там.

Comment: settings -> file types -> настроить дополнительную маску для PHP

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!